# How can I create a favicon locally with a script?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, favicon

I've been using http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/ for years now for generating favicons. I started using it before I even knew how to do any coding (I'm not great now). I don't mind using the utility because the icons always look pretty good, but I'd love to be able to do it locally.

How can I create a favicon locally with a script? Somehow with PHP, imagemagick / gd  or maybe sips from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use imagemagik convert. I took these commands from [this website](http://bergamini.org/computers/creating-favicon.ico-icon-files-with-imagemagick-convert.html).

First make a master image:

> `convert some_image.bmp -resize 256x256 -transparent white
>   favicon-256.png`
>
> Then we'll want to make images for each size you want to include in
>   the .ico file.
>
> `convert favicon-256.png -resize 16x16 favicon-16.png`
>
> `convert favicon-256.png -resize 32x32 favicon-32.png`
>
> `convert favicon-256.png -resize 64x64 favicon-64.png`
>
> `convert favicon-256.png -resize 128x128 favicon-128.png`
>
> Now you'll want to bundle them up into the .ico file, the trick I
>   found is to make it 256 colors or it will not display properly!
>
> `convert favicon-16.png favicon-32.png favicon-64.png favicon-128.png
>   favicon-256.png -colors 256 favicon.ico`

Answer (score 3):

ImageMagick or phpThumb will do this for you but a simpler solution (requiring only PHP and the the GD library) is https://github.com/chrisbliss18/php-ico

Answer (score 1):

Check out this script:
http://bgallz.org/488/php-favicon-generator-script/

I wrote it using PHP to generate a favicon (.ico) file from a jpeg, gif, or png. As ernie above said, most browsers now support image files for icons. This script just alters the extension on the file to be ".ico"

As I have:

```
// Rename image to .ico file
rename($filename,"./favicon/".$strip_ext.".ico");
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a project just for this: [faviconbuild](https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/faviconbuild/).

I built it with two simple scripts (one .bat for Windows and one .sh for Unix, Mac, and Windows if using Cygwin).  It relies on [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) so you can download the latest version of that for your platform or get it from the ones I include in the [releases](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild/releases).

I have released it under the [MIT license](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild/blob/master/LICENSE) so feel free to use it for commercial or personal projects or to simply use as inspiration for your own scripts.

I currently use it in my own project like this:

```
./faviconbuild/faviconbuild.sh -i ./source.png
```

You can get a full list of the commands available with the `-h` or `--help` options.

This will take an input source image and generate all of the output images and a multiresolution .ico, along with the html markup needed for your website.

The script can also be customized by providing a custom text based parse file as input.  The current file can be found in the project [here](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild/blob/master/favinput.txt).  This allows the scripts to be easily extended for any project on all platforms.

Since it is hosted on [github](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild) I encourage anyone to contribute to the project even if just by submitting a feature request.

I have also published a [blog post](https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/2015/10/10/faviconbuild/) that goes over the development and serves as a mini tutorial on bash/batch.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is resize an image as a 16x16 file.  While the ICO format used to be standard, modern browsers can handle [PNG, GIF, and JPG (among other formats)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support).

Resize scripts can easily be found by googling for them, e.g.:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

This script updates existing files, you might need to alter it for your project. Remove the "confirm" line, or grab my confirm script to go with it.

WARNING: It will clobber any `.png` file in the current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
# public domain, by Sam Watkins
echo "You need to run this from a directory containing only the png icons."
confirm "Are you in the icons directory?"
source=`readlink -f "$1"`
chmod -w $source
v convert "$source" -resize 512x512 -background white -alpha remove -alpha off tmp-512-white.png
v convert "$source" -resize 512x512 tmp-512.png
sizes="16 32 64 128 256"
favicons=
for W in $sizes; do
    F=favicon-${W}x$W.png
    v convert tmp-512.png -resize ${W}x$W $F
    favicons="$favicons $F"
done
v convert $favicons -colors 256 favicon.ico

for F in *.png; do
    case "$F" in
    favicon-*)
        ;;
    apple-touch-icon*)
        v convert tmp-512-white.png -resize `identify -format "%wx%h" "$F"` "$F"
        ;;
    *)
        v convert tmp-512.png -resize `identify -format "%wx%h" "$F"` "$F"
        ;;
    esac
done
rm -f tmp-512-white.png tmp-512.png
```

https://ucm.dev/b/make-icons

https://ucm.dev/b/confirm